# Cannot change Tailwind styles using variables in React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am building a skeleton which is consisted of 1 big div and 8 small divs. And to that small divs I want to give different widths. I did styling with variables like in my other component, but while mapping It does not work, Tailwind just not apply those styles.

My code:

```
import { FC } from 'react';

const randomWidthArray = ["110", "94", "123", "87", "93", "113", "125", "120"]

const CategorySkeleton: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col w-[300px] border-r border-r-[#D5D5D5] gap-y-[8px]">
      <div className="w-[150px] h-[28px] mb-[14px] bg-[#D5D5D5]"></div>
      {randomWidthArray.map((width: string, idx: number) => {
        const widthStyle = `w-[${width}px]`;
        return <div key={idx} className={`h-[19px] bg-[#D5D5D5] ${widthStyle}`}></div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CategorySkeleton;

In this screen we can see, that everything was written right, but Tailwind does not recognise w-[100px] as a style (at the right side of the screen it is seen)
```

[image]

I tried to use number and string types as width variables, I also tried to create a string with this style (like w-[123px]) and then add to the classname, I created that inside of classname but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind uses regex to find class names, and because of this they need to exist as unbroken strings in your source code. A consequence of this is [you cannot use string interpolation the way you're trying to do](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names), as Tailwind will not be able to find the class name.

What you can do instead is map your props to static class names:

```js
import { FC } from 'react';

const randomWidthArray = ["110", "94", "123", "87", "93", "113", "125", "120"]

const CategorySkeleton: FC = () => {
  const widthVariants = {
    "110": "w-[110px]",
    "94": "w-[94px]",
    // ...
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col w-[300px] border-r border-r-[#D5D5D5] gap-y-[8px]">
      <div className="w-[150px] h-[28px] mb-[14px] bg-[#D5D5D5]"></div>
      {randomWidthArray.map((width: string, idx: number) => {
        const widthStyle = widthVariants[width];
        return <div key={idx} className={`h-[19px] bg-[#D5D5D5] ${widthStyle}`}></div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```