# tailwind fill class isn't applied

Tags: css, svg, next.js, tailwind-css

Working with SVGs and tailwind, I'm applying a `fill-primary` on one of the instance, but my SVG remains black.

```
<svg width="9622" height="127" viewBox="0 0 9622 127" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="wave" d="..." fill="currentColor"/>
</svg>
```

```
<svg className={`block w-full scale-y-75 origin-bottom`}>
  <use
    xlinkHref="/wave.svg#wave"
    className={`fill-${color-var}`}
    <--! ${color-var} outputs primary -->
  />            
</svg
```

My colors are defined in my `tailwind.config.js` as I'm using multiple instances of `bg-color` elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Tailwind will not recognize your `fill-${color-var}` class because it only works with explicitly defined classes in the config such as `fill-primary`, `fill-red-600` . For short, tailwind does not recognize dynamic class names.

I believe this has previously been answered on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75565360/9775615).

More on this and possible workarounds, depending on your specific project needs -> [Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

Hope it helps!